# Saving Value from check to mysql database (Angular Js,J2EE,Mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, jakarta-ee

I am getting all the data from database as array- so In view my code is-

```
<tr role="row" ng-repeat="result in searchResults">
<td class="sorting_1"><input type="checkbox"
ng-model="result.status" ng-change="saveCheckboxValue(result.status)"/></td>
</tr>
```

On clicking checkbox i want to update the value, my js :-

```
    $scope.saveCheckboxValue = function(data){
    $scope.result.status=  (data == true ? 1 : 0);
    alert($scope.result.status);
    var successCallback = function(){
        $.growl.notice({ message: "Updated successfully!" });
        $location.path("/Attendance");
        //$scope.get();
        $scope.displayError = false;
    };
    var errorCallback = function() {
        $scope.displayError=true;
    };
    $scope.result.$update(successCallback, errorCallback);  
    }
```

I am getting error :

```
PUT localhost...... 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Help with solution or idea , How can i do it?

Comment: Issue is server related not client side

Comment: You probably don't have a request handler for this request